# google map api v3 - Draw line proceeding X meters north of a give point

Tags: google-maps-api-3

User supplies a location (City,State or postal code). I get the lat/long and set a marker.  I want to start by drawing a line x meters (distance also supplied by user) North, emanating from the marker.

Eventually, I want to radiate equidistant lines out North, South, East and West of the marker, based on the distance supplied by the user.

It would look like this (going East and west)

-------------------------------X-------------------------------

I'm only going to have the one point; the lat/long of the user's location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page should help...

[Lat/Long manipulations page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: Boo, that link was asbolutely 100% spot on. I've got it working just as I imagined it.  Thanks!!